# Spring Integration loads file everytime the application is restarted

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a SFTP inbound adapter which gets the file from SFTP and saves the file in local directory. Even though the file is deleted from SFTP location, the application reads the file after every restart of the server. I am assuming that it reads the file from local directory. Is this expected or is there any work around? I want the application to read from SFTP location only. If the file is deleted from SFTP then the application should not read the file on restart of application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` in the `local-filter` instead of the default `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` which keeps its state in memory; see [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound).

Alternatively, remove the local file once processing is complete.